# request.getAttribute not working in included file

Tags: java, jsp, attributes, include

In my Dynamic Web Application (working in Eclipse, with Tomcat 7 server), my pages have the same header, which includes the username of the currently logged in user.

Rather than having the header appear identically on each page, I extracted and included

```
<%@ include file="../includes/head.jsp" %>
```

to the top of each .jsp.

But I noticed a problem. In the Servlet files I created I have a variation of (depending on the jsp page):

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Login doGet");
        request.setAttribute("name", "value");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("resources/jsp/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

However, in the **head.jsp** file,

```
${request.getAttribute("name") != null ? "Logged In" : "Not logged in"}
```

is causing "Not logged in" to appear when I'm expecting it to say "Logged In" (because I did pass an attribute called "name".

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: request.getSession().setAttribute....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= request.getAttribute("name") == null ? "Logged In" : "Not logged in" %>
```

Works because you have used the scriptlets to print the request attributes in the traditional way. However it is considered as bad practice . see [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

```
${request.getAttribute("name") == null ? "Logged In" : "Not logged in"}
```

Doesnt work because you have incorrect syntax of [`Expression Language`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

so either use [jstl](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) as @user23123412 suggested or write it as ,

```
${name == null ? "Logged In" : "Not logged in"}
```

to evaluate using EL

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

You should use request.getSession().setAttribute("name", "value");

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work eventually by using this

```
<%= request.getAttribute("name") == null ? "Logged In" : "Not logged in" %>
```

instead of the original

```
${request.getAttribute("name") == null ? "Logged In" : "Not logged in"}
```

I tried this after I saw that this is another way to write expressions. I have no idea why this way works and the other way doesn't and would love if some could add an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use JSTL for this manner. Its better way to use jstl rather than scriptlets.

```
<c:out value="${empty name ? 'Logged In' : 'Not logged in' }" />
```